# How to add extra preview when adding widget on screen using requestPinAppWidget?

Tags: android, widget, remoteview

I saw in documentation:

> EXTRA_APPWIDGET_PREVIEW
>
> An extra that can be passed to
>   requestPinAppWidget(android.content.ComponentName, android.os.Bundle,
>   android.app.PendingIntent).

So I tried to something like:

```
...
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_PREVIEW, R.drawable.preview_new);
appWidgetManager.requestPinAppWidget(myWidgetProvider, b, successCallback);
```

But seems like bundle b is completely ignored (it doesnt change preview).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Replace your Bundle with :

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
b.putParcelable(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_PREVIEW, remoteViews);
```

Ref : https://medium.com/wearebase/android-oreo-widget-pinning-in-kotlin-398d529eab28